# Why is Iterator::rev defined on Iterator and not DoubleEndedIterator

Tags: rust, iterator, bidirectional

Rust has two main traits for iteration: the standard [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html) for things that can be traversed in order, and [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html) for things that can additionally be iterated from the back.

This makes sense to me. A lot of useful methods are defined on `Iterator`, like `map`, `filter`, and whatnot. And then things that operate from the "back", so to speak, like `rfind` and `rfold` are defined on `DoubleEndedIterator` since such operations only make sense on such iterators.

But then we've got [`Iterator::rev`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#3032-3037)

> ```
> fn rev(self) -> Rev<Self>
> where
>     Self: Sized + DoubleEndedIterator,
> {
>     Rev::new(self)
> }
> ```

`rev` is a function defined on `Iterator` but with an additional constraint on `Self` that it be `DoubleEndedIterator` as well.

What is the practical benefit to having this function defined on `Iterator`? We can only call it on `DoubleEndedIterator` implementors, and `DoubleEndedIterator` extends `Iterator` so we'll never end up in a situation where something implements the former and not the latter. So why is `rev` not defined on `DoubleEndedIterator` like `rfind` and `rfold` are?

Comment: it's always better to try to answer "why not"

Comment: For what it's worth, here is [the relevant commit](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/de1446680cab4102cef9d0e133f1b835574926eb). The method used to be on a trait called `DoubleEndedIteratorExt` that required `DoubleEndedIterator + Sized`. The `DoubleEndedIteratorExt` trait was then merged into `Iterator`. I can't see why it wasn't merged into `DoubleEndedIterator` instead.

Comment: If you need to call it statically or pass it as the function per se, it's a bit nicer to write `Iterator::rev` than `DoubleEndedIterator::rev`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach nevermind merge it would force every implementation of Iterator to implement `Rev` aka be a doubleendediterator and OP didn't ask for why it's not merged

Comment: There are a couple more methods that require `DoubleEndedIterator` on the `Iterator` triait, `partition_in_place()` and `rposition()`. Looking at the methods that are on `DoubleEndedIterator` proper, it looks like they are the ones that are useful to specialize for specific bidirectional iterators, while the ones on the `Iterator` trait generally are not useful to specialize. Whether this is the reason they are split up this way, I don't know. I also don't see a forcing reason why it should be this way, since methods on either trait could be specialized.

Answer (score 4):

This allow to:

- see all features (doc) of `Iterator` in one place.
- use `rev()` on an `Iterator` without need to `use DoubleEndedIterator`, the [`prelude`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/v1/index.html) include it so it's not a problem actually. I would so add this reduce cognitive load by letting the user ignore `DoubleEndedIterator` exist.

Comment: I'm not sure this really explains why `rev()` is treated differently than the methods that are directly defined on the `DoubleEndedIterator` trait.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I don't even see why these other method exist the all can be replace by `rev().foo()` like `rfold()` == `.rev().fold()` so there are not needed on Iterator directly, I guess there exist for optimisation purpose.

Comment: @SvenMarnach All but `rfind()` are methods the iterator can, or should, implement to make the various iteration options faster. I don't know why `rfind()` is also there.

Comment: The first argument is not enough since `DoubleEndedIterator` is [in the prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/v1/index.html).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman wow... strange.. nice catch... this reduce the list to one..... :p it's a wiki answer to feel free to change it